# Content View to sort results to match the users Profile 2 taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

I have a taxonomy term that gets assigned to a content type via entity reference, and the Drupal user, via Profile 2.

I want to add a filter to a content view that matches the 2 up, so if you filled in your user profile saying you only interested in x, have a view that only show content that was assigned with the same term.

I have tried adding author, profile2, taxonomy term relationships etc without any luck. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this:
The key is to start with an **User View**.
**Add Relationship -> User: Profile**
Pick the profile where the taxonomy was assigned.
**Add Relationship -> Content: Taxonomy terms on node**
Pick your vocabulary.
**Add Relationship -> User: Content authored**
**Add Contextual filter -> Content: Has taxonomy term ID**
Choose PHP as a Provide default value option:

```
global $user;
$profiles = profile2_load_by_user($user);
    foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
      if ($items = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, 'field_your_interests')) {
        break;
      }
    }
$tids = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $tids[] = $item['tid'];
}
return implode('+', $tids);
```

Then add the fields and additional filters as needed.

Resources:
http://blog.ampli.fi/filtering-a-drupal-7-view-based-on-multiple-user-profile-fields/
https://www.drupal.org/node/1111722#comment-4315620
[Drupal terms and arrays](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171633/drupal-terms-and-arrays/171641) - thanks Aaron!