# Drupal terms and arrays

Tags: views

I am struggling a bit with the array structure of Drupal.

I am using PHP in a contextual filter inside views. I have the same vocab on both a content type and user via profile2. I manage to get the filter working for single term. The key is in how I return the values at the end of my function.

```
return $items[0]['tid'];
```

This returns 2, a correct tid on user profile taxonomy.

I can also get other values by using:

```
return $items[1]['tid'];
```

This returns 4, also a correct tid.

How would I be able to say?

```
return $items[ALL_ARRAYS]['tid'];
```

So that it would print all the term ids associated with that vocab?

My PHP code:

```
global $user;
$profiles = profile2_load_by_user($user);
    foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
      if ($items = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, 'field_your_interests')) {
        break;
      }
    }
$tids = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $tids[] = $item['tid'];
}
//returns nothing in view, not sure if a contextual filter can handle 'and'?
//return implode(',', $tids);

//This works with 1st value in array 
//return $items[0]['tid'];

//This doesn't return anything
  return $tids;
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please don't use [tag:php]: You are not asking a question about PHP. Drupal is then written in PHP; if we were to use this tag just because the question shown PHP code, 99% of the questions here will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, but this is probably the most straightforward:

```
$tids = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $tids[] = $item['tid'];
}

// Return this if you want to use "or" logic
return implode('+', $tids);

// Return this if you want to use "and" logic
return implode(',', $tids);
```

Comment: thanks this helped. By using dpm($tids); i can see that the array is only made up of the desired id's. I tried using the add logic to return the values, but my view keeps returning an empty result. I updated my original code to include all my code, as you can see I'm still new to this :)

Comment: @Ddroid_za do you have your contextual filter set to allow multiple values?  In the settings for the contextual filter, near the bottom, I think it's under the "more" link.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Aaron.Yes I did, both the multiple "Allow multiple values" and "Allow multiple filter values to work together" checkboxes are ticked under the More section. I also made sure the distinct option is not turned on in the query settings. By providing a default fixed value in the contextual filter it all works 100%.

Comment: @Ddroid_za Many folks get confused on the difference between "and" and "or" logic.  Please try `return implode('+', $tids);`  as I suspect you're more interested in "or" logic than "and" logic.  Also: note that you can test it by manually entering arguments in the live preview.  Try putting in `2+4` (or, if you really do want "and", `2,4`) in as an argument in the live preview to see if it gives you what you expect.

Comment: You sir are my hero! Thanks the '+' works perfectly!